# My api is return a :ok when should be returning a :unprocessable_entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have an API that I'm currently using rspec to do the tests. In a specific test, I do a patch/put in a unity giving invalid values, but when I do the same test he responds with a status ":ok" and not a ":unprocessable_entity" as they should.

The test:

```
it "renders a JSON response with errors for the new unit" do
  post units_url,
  params: { unit: invalid_attributes }, headers: valid_headers, as: :json
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
  expect(response.content_type).to match(a_string_including("application/vnd.api+json"))
end
```

The update on unit_controller.rb:

```
def update
  if @unit.update!(unit_params)
    render json: @unit
  else
    render json: @unit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

The unit_params:

```
def unit_params
  params.require(:unit).permit(:name)
end
```

The response:[image: A image where i pass invalid parameters but the system accept them anyway]

Comment: ```def unit_params
      params.require(:unit).permit(:name)
end```, even if i remove the "!" still not working

Comment: ```validates :name, presence: true```, and in the migration ":name" only allowed to recieve a string ```t.string :name```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send such params

```json
{
  "unit": {
    "name": ""
  }
}
```

You don't need `update!` method because it raises error if validations fail. Use `update` (without bang) instead